# I2C interference SENSOR(SCL+SDA) and MasterSlave comm

Tags: i2c, nodemcu

I am building a weather station with an Arduino slave (dedicated to a rain gauge - depicted below as a reed switch) and a NodeMCU master with some additional sensors.

[image: Arduino slave NodeMCU master]

One such sensor, a BMP280 uses D1 and D2 as SCL and SDA, while slave control is using D3 and D4 for communication with Arduino.

When I enable `Wire.begin` for slave communication, my BMP280 readings go nuts

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

#define BMP_SCK 13
#define BMP_MISO 12
#define BMP_MOSI 11 
#define BMP_CS 10

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp;

// masterSlave
#include <Wire.h>
#define I2CAddressESPWifi 8
...

void setup() {

    if (!bmp.begin()) {  
        Serial.println("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring!");
        while (1);
    }

    // masterSlave - generates problem with BMP280...
    Wire.begin(0,2);//Change to Wire.begin() for non ESP. D3 SDA  D4 SCL
```

> BMP280 Temp = -136.42 *C
>
> Pressure = 125136.25 Pa

as opposed to this reading when Wire.begin is commented out.

```cpp
    // COMMENTED OUT FOR DEBUGGING
    //masterSlave - generates problem with BMP280...
    //Wire.begin(0,2);//Change to Wire.begin() for non ESP. D3 SDA  D4 SCL
```

> BMP280 Temp = 20.01 *C
>
> Pressure = 93464.36 Pa

I attempted setting D3 and D4 to LOW while reading from BMP280, but it had no effect on readings.

Comment: Hint#1: I2C pullup resistors.

Comment: share your full sketch here.

Comment: The I2C is designed for short distances on a PCB. How far will be the slave?

Comment: @Juraj some few centimeters - same board (there's a 10m extension cable for the rain gauge -  that part is working perfectly).

Comment: @MikaelPatel I'll play some more with the pullup resistor and get back to you.

Comment: @Vaibhav 1300 lines of code...  Which parts interest most?  until setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Adafruit BMP280 library uses the Wire library. It calls begin() at default pins (D1, D2). And then you begin() the same Wire object at different pins. From that moment the BMP280 library can't communicate with the sensor.

The I2C (a.k.a. TwoWire or Wire) is a bus. Many devices can be wired to the same pair of pins. They must listen on different addresses. So wire both devices to the D1, D2 and use in slave Arduino an address different then the address of the sensor.

The esp8266 and the sensor are 3.3 V devices. The Uno is a 5 V device. You should use logic level conversion on SDA/SCL to Uno.

Comment: So, as far as I2C is concerned, the sensor can be addressed as a slave.  I'll try that and get back to you by the end of the day.  Makes total sense.  UPVOTED

Comment: not "to be addressed". but "having an address". some sensors have fixed address, some have a choice from a few addreses

Comment: yeah, i'll check up on that.  I'll start by changing the slave's address (currently `8`)

Comment: the default I2C address of the Adafruit BMP280 is 0x77

Comment: I attempted this solution with no result.

Comment: this is not a solution but an explanation. what is wrong after you use the Wire library on one set of pins?

Comment: when i place the slave and the sendor on the same set of pins is that the sensor is not recognized.

Comment: on D1, D1 and you removed Wire.begin(0, 2)?

Comment: yes, i did.  everything using D1 and D2, removed `Wire.begin(0,2)`.  Sensor works without slave, but when slave is wired in, sensor stops being recognized

Comment: @tonygil, the slave Arduino works without the sensor on esp8266?

Comment: 50 bonus points for effort, even though i havent at, at this time, been able to confirm or disprove this answer because of other incidental issues which arise AND because of my limited knowledge of `Wire` library.

Comment: I added a note about logic level conversion. and thank you.

Comment: got it working.  fixed connections and set a small delay before reading

Answer (score 1):

As per your descriptions, I'm answering here. There is a fact we forget about the load capacitance calculation for selecting I2C pull-ups. It's calculated when more than one slave and variant to distance. Check the jumpers and for pullups try 10k or 4.7K or better you can calculate. It's better to provide a small delay after the wire.begin() function to stabilize the module

Comment: would you care to scribble that on the fritzing diagram in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented uses the BMP280 sensor in SPI mode, connected as follows:

[image: Breadboard scheme]

with this code before `setup`

```
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>
#define BMP_SCK D5
#define BMP_MISO D8
#define BMP_MOSI D6 
#define BMP_CS D7

//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // I2C
//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS); // hardware SPI
Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS, BMP_MOSI, BMP_MISO,  BMP_SCK);
```

Comment: which doesnt EXACTLY answer my answer, though it solves the practical problem (just in case anyone wants a workaround).  ;)